# Predicate Query for CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I want to write a search function using `NSPredicate` to search for the start of an element [Not contains, which I currently have but start].

Right now my predicate is:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
```

How can I search the string from the start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BEGINSWITH` instead of `CONTAINS`. Note that you can still use `[cd]` when using `BEGINSWITH`.

See the full documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Comment: Thanks Wain !! Again :)